# Чермное море — смысл названия

Tags: этимология

В Библии в Ветхом Завете упоминается Чермное море. Судя по всему, речь идет о Красном море. Но что означает слово "чермное"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чермное — красное, красивое.

"Червлень" — так именуется в геральдике красный цвет. Красноватое золото — "червонное". Эти слова, как и "чермное", происходят от названия червецов — насекомых, из которых добывали красную краску во всей Eвропе.

Традиционно принято отождествлять Чермное море с Красным морем; тем не менее, возможно, это был какой-то другой географический объект: залив Красного моря или одно из озёр между Египтом и Израилем, например, на Суэцком перешейке.